# The application does not have a valid signature Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, xcode

When I run my project in simulator it works fine. But run the project in real device always gave me a app installation failed message which is:

> 'The application does not have a valid signature'

I have valid developer certificate, provisioning profile. I cleaned my project, removed Derived Data but nothing solved my problem yet. [screenshot what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDYpj.jpg)

Comment: i am using cocoapods in my projects.

Comment: Can you share the full error you are getting?

Comment: i am not getting any error log.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project build settings, look for section "Code Signing":

- Make sure your (correct and valid) developer certificate is selected under "Code Signing
  Identity"
- Make sure "Provisioning Profile" is set to "Automatic"

See screenshot:

[image]

If still not working:

- Open keychain app
- Look for your developer certificate and make sure it is **valid and has
  no duplicates** (if there are duplicates, delete and leave one valid
  certificate only)
- Open Xcode and go to preferences
- Select "Accounts" tab
- Select your Apple ID user
- Double click on your team (in the bottom right side of the window)
- Right click on any provision profile (bottom list)
- Select "Show in finder"
- Delete all files in that folder
- Go back to Xcode window, and click on "Download All"
- Press "Done"
- Try to re-build project

If still not working, let me know.

Comment: I followed your both instructions but it always give me the same result.

Comment: Is it any kind of Cocoapods issue ? i am using Cocoapods for the first time.

Comment: Try to isolate the issue, remove cocoapods from project and see if that fix the issue. if yes, then you probably (but less likely) will need to set codesign settings in cocoapods output as well.

Comment: it's a Cocoapods issue. i removed cocoapods & it fixes my problem. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

I was with the same problem.

I installed the last update of OS X and my problem was fixed!

I hope that it can help you!